# How to do loop in pentaho for getting file names?

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I have 100 000 files.
I want to get the name of those file names and have to put in database, 
I have to do like this

1. get 10 files name's;
2. update/insert names into  database;   and
3. move those 10 files to another directory; 
   and loop these three steps till no files are found.

Is this possible?

Comment: why do you need to do it in 10 file chunks? you should really just load everything in the directory in a step and process on through from there. further, loops are not something you want to create in kettle.

Comment: If I load it directly from directory its not working its running out of memory eventhough i increase MAXSIZE its showing error

Answer (score 6):

I'm attaching a working example (I tested it with ~400 text files on kettle 4.3.).

[transformation.ktr](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B_C8tdbiOkEAX09rYW5vdXVyZlk)
[job.kjb](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B_C8tdbiOkEATmRMM2hrMDZnWGc)

Both transformation and job contain detailed notes on what to set and where.

- **Transformation.ktr** It reads first 10 filenames from given source folder, creates destination filepath for file moving. It outputs filenames to insert/update (I used dummy step as a placeholder) and uses "Copy rows to resultset" to output needed source and destination paths for file moving.
- **job.kjb** All the looping is done in this job. It executes "transformation.ktr" (which does insert/update for 10 files), and then moves those 10 files to destination folder. After that, it checks whether there's any more files in source folder. If there is, process is repeated, if not, it declares success.

Comment: If this is working for you, you might want to mark my answer as answerd :) Thank you.